# Failed to load resource, a general issue of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, hugo

Error Message: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Hi,

I deploy my website on AWS AMPLIFY, using HUGO. However, I just find a general issue of loading web resources. The error message is above, and the web is `allonsygamma.com`.

Git repo: https://github.com/yinxiangshi/newhp

Plz help me with this.

Load resources normally.

Comment: I am able to access `allonsygamma.com` successfully. Where are these errors appearing, and what is the impact of these errors?

Comment: The error is not loading the pics. You can check the web console, there are two errors. This issue was just solved by the admin of hugo: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/a-common-issue-of-aws-amplify/41416

Comment: Great to hear that you have fixed your problem! If you have a solution, please post an Answer to your question to help future readers. Or, if the problem was outside of your control, you are welcome to delete this Question if it will not assist future readers.

Comment: I will attach a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To help future readers:

If u meet this problem, you need to follow modify:

First, in your `baseURL`, you need to set this:

`baseURL=https://www.your_domain/`

Then, in your layout HTML files, change all the URL refer from `'{{ .Site.BaseURL }}/picname.jpg'` to `'{{ "picname.jpg" | absURL }}'`

For more info, you can see: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/a-common-issue-of-aws-amplify/41416/2